# Detect the system folder located in computer, rather than just a string

Tags: c#, winforms

I already deploy my application (simple application), and I tested it on my computer and the result looks fine because system folder on my computer located in `C: Drive`, but when I tested it on my friend computer where the system folder on his computer located in `D: Drive`, I got the error says (Translated to my own words) `The sound cannot be played due to the unspecified system media folder`, this happens because I used this following code:

```
public static void SoundEffect(string _soundLocation)
        {
            _soundPlayer.SoundLocation = _soundLocation;
            _soundPlayer.Play();
        }

SystemManager.SoundEffect("C:/Windows/Media/Speech Off.wav");
```

SystemManager is the class where the `SoundEffect` function located.

My question is: How do I detect the windows system folder for the sound on the user computer? So, rather back to my case above, I would like to just detect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to look on [SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration.
Especially on its `CommonMusic` member, which is available from the 4.0 version of framework.

So your code may look like:

```
 var musicFile = System.IO.Path.Combine("Speech  Off.wav", 
                    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonMusic));

 SystemManager.SoundEffect(musicFile);
```

Comment: So, for loads or plays the music or whatever it is that requires system folder on the computers, we have to use `Environment.SpecialFolder` instead?

Comment: Yes, that's right. That property links you to concrete path on the given machine, and you stop being biased by the fixed paths in your code.